# How to replace Facebook Android SDK replace Session.OpenRequest

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I found Facebook Android SDK has deprecated its class Session in its 4.x version. What class or method I should use to replace Session.OpenRequest? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes you need to look into are CallbackManager and LoginManager (and also AccessToken).  I replaced my old Session.OpenRequest code with something akin to the following, it may be helpful as a starting point:

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    m_CallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(m_CallbackManager,
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            completeLogin();
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancel() {
            // TODO: this

          }

          @Override
          public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // TODO: this
          }
        });

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
```